# Columns overlap xAxis labels

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have made a Graph with R/rCharts/highcharts inside a markdown document. I produce a plot which includes (besides other commands) this command, which causes the problem in rmarkdown:

```
plot$yAxis(labels = list(formatter = "#! function() {return (this.value) + '%';} !#"),

                        # The maximum value should always be 100
                        max = 100,

                        # Subtract 5 percent from the minimum value as 
                        # minimum value for the y Axis.
                        min = max(minimum - 5, 0))
```

Which looks just fine when I look at it in rStudio viewer:

[image]

However, when I use the same code inside rmarkdown, the columns seem to start on the wrong position:

[image]

Which is caused by the hard setting of the yAxis minimum value. The code creating the error in markdown is exactly the same as above. Only to plot, i use this command:

`plot$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)`

The columns start position does not seem to be updated.. 
Do you have any idea what causes the error?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the problem, but have to ask why you have a column chart with a non-zero start point? It seems that starting at zero would both be the correct thing to do, and would possibly solve the problem also

Comment: The values I am plotting are efficiency values close to 100% so scaling them from 0 to 100% would not give any information because the values are like 98%, 97%, 96.5%, 99% and so on. I want to see a difference in the height of the graph.

Comment: In that case I would use a dot plot instead of a column. Columns that don't start at 0 are inescapably misleading.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this idea. I will definitely give it a try. Nonetheless I would like to understand why my plot is not working as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure about R/rCharts but in Highcharts, you can set [`plotOptions.column.threshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.threshold) to start rendering columns from `min` value. Or set it to null, and resign from setting min, that should resolve the issue to.

Comment: Can you explain that further? If I use treshold, my output bars are just moved up the amount of threshold, so my bars get way beyond 100%

Comment: Maybe wrapper is broken? See demo with all examples: http://jsfiddle.net/sjr65gh9/ Examples are: #1 = threshold=null, #2 = threshold=yAxis.min, #3 = default threshold.